# How to update and format every fields of a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-update

I want to modify every field in a column to add a space after the 4th character.

> AAAAFoo => AAAA Foo
>
> TOTOBar => TOTO Bar

I think I should use update using regex or something like that but I don't know how...

Comment: [This has been discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/give-me-teh-regez-questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something as simple as:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = STUFF([Column],5,0,' ');
```

[`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

> The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.

So in the above, 5 is the start position, we delete 0 characters from the string, and then we insert a single space.

Comment: If it was, why don't you accept it as answered?

Comment: Sorry, new on Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `substring` function as below:

```
update table
set column1 = substring(column1,1,4)+' '+substring(column1,5,len(column1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    column1 = SUBSTRING(column1, 1, 4) + ' ' +
                 SUBSTRING(column1, 5, LEN(column1) - 4)
```